# Any reason why this definite integral is so slow to compute and the indefinite fast?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This integral is easy and fast to compute

```
Integrate[Sqrt[(x^2) + k ], x]
```

> $$\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{k+x^2}+\frac{1}{2} k \log \left(\sqrt{k+x^2}+x\right)$$

But the same, *definite*, integral is very slow:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[x^2 + k], {x, Sqrt[u], Sqrt[u] + Sqrt[A]}]
```

I suspect this is related with conditions about parameter (cannot see any other reason) but I didn't managed to put proper `Assumptions` to make it execute faster.

I can compute the definite integral by the indefinite one with

```
Integrate[Sqrt[x^2 + k], x] /. {{x -> Sqrt[u] + Sqrt[A]}, {x -> Sqrt[u]}} // Apply@Subtract
```

but, if possible, I prefer to keep the definite form, with the proper options and assumptions.

Comment: Well, the big difference between an indefinite integral and a definite one in Mathematica is that for the latter the machinery tries to detect discontinuities that would invalidate your method. That's a difficult and not perfectly reliable process.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the definite integral you have to make assumptions about the parameters.
The natural choice for the parameters u and A is that they are positive.
Letting, for simplicity, also k> 0 we find

```
g = Timing[ 
  Integrate[Sqrt[x^2 + k], {x, Sqrt[u], Sqrt[u] + Sqrt[A]}, 
   Assumptions -> {u > 0, A > 0, k > 0}]]

(* Out[162]= {1.85641, 1/
  2 (-Sqrt[u (k + u)] + Sqrt[A (A + k + u + 2 Sqrt[A u])] + Sqrt[
    u (A + k + u + 2 Sqrt[A u])] + 
    k Log[(Sqrt[A] + Sqrt[u] + Sqrt[A + k + u + 2 Sqrt[A u]])/(
      Sqrt[u] + Sqrt[k + u])])} *)
```

For comparison the indefinite integral is

```
f = Timing[Integrate[Sqrt[x^2 + k], x]]

(* Out[163]= {0.0312002, 1/2 x Sqrt[k + x^2] + 1/2 k Log[x + Sqrt[k + x^2]]} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this blog post answers your question.

http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/

It boils down to this:

The fundamental theorem of Calculus requires the antiderivative be continuous. This is something hard to guarantee and can be slow to detect and fix the discontinuities by shifting vertically.